# Why is this dd command with a count and bs param running past its count?

Tags: dd

I have a `dd` command with `bs=1M` and `count=40960M` (40GB) and it's consistently running past its count every time I try to run it. This is the exact command, and the output captured before I stop it:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile bs=1M count=40960M status=progress
50383028224 bytes (50 GB, 47 GiB) copied, 458 s, 110 MB/s
```

Based on the progress output, it seems like it's just running indefinitely and probably would keep going until the `of` destination is completely filled. What am I misunderstanding about `dd` that's causing this to keep running forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to multiply the `bs` and `count` parameters to get the siez fo the data it will actually write. You're asking it to write 40 billion (40960 million) blocks, each block being 1 MB large. That's... quite a large amount of data.

If you want to write 40 GB, you can use `bs=1 count=40960M`, `bs=1M count=40960`, or some similar combination.

Comment: The two options you have offered will result in the same size destination, but the first will take a mind bogglingly longer time to complete. (For a 10MB example, `bs=1 count=10M` vs `bs=1M count=10` reading and writing `/dev/zero`, the difference is 16s vs 0.006s.)

Comment: ‍♂️ That makes a lot more sense and explains what's going on here. I guess I should RTFM more carefully...

Answer (score 1):

The count parameter in the `dd` specifies the number of blocks to be copied, and the `bs` parameter determines the block size.

`dd` interprets the `M` suffix represent "million" as a binary multiplier.

`count=40960M`  in the count parameter means 40,960 million blocks, not megabytes.

Which results in a much larger size than you intended.

Remove the `M` suffix to calculate the correct value for count.

This is the correct command:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile bs=1M count=40960 status=progress`